# How do I merge strings\sentences from same user using regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I'm trying to merge sentences in python using regex patterns to get my data in an organized format but am finding it difficult.

the original data format im trying to merge is as follows

```
chat_segment = 
"""
13:54:09: Hello, thank you for visiting. Can I help you in any way?
Visitor: 13:47:16: I want to book a ticket from Thailand to Hawai
Visitor: 13:47:49: On 18th this month
Sam: 13:48:03: Hi
Sam: 13:48:18: Which class would you like the ticket in?
Visitor: 13:48:40: Business
Sam: 13:48:43: Give me a minute to check availability
Visitor: 13:48:55: ok
Sam: 13:49:41: Only one ticket available on 18th in business class.
Sam: 13:50:02: The ticket costs 500$.
Sam: 13:50:31: And the flight departs at 8 am"""
```

I am trying to get it into the following format where sentences from the same users are merged together.

```
['Visitor: I want to book a ticket from Thailand to Hawai On 18th this month','Sam: Hi Which class would you like the ticket in?','Visitor: Business','Sam: Give me a minute to check availability','Visitor: ok','Sam: Only one ticket available on 18th in business class. The ticket costs 500$. And the flight departs at 8 am']
```

This is the code I tried which splits sentences based on timestamp, but i could not figure out a way to merge sentences on same users. Please note that "visitor" name is same but name "sam" changes.

```
chat_tokenised = re.split(r"\d+:\d+:\d+:\s+",chat_segment)
print(chat_tokenised)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) to group items together:

```
chat_segment = """
13:54:09: Hello, thank you for visiting. Can I help you in any way?
Visitor: 13:47:16: I want to book a ticket from Thailand to Hawai
Visitor: 13:47:49: On 18th this month
Sam: 13:48:03: Hi
Sam: 13:48:18: Which class would you like the ticket in?
Visitor: 13:48:40: Business
Sam: 13:48:43: Give me a minute to check availability
Visitor: 13:48:55: ok
Sam: 13:49:41: Only one ticket available on 18th in business class.
Sam: 13:50:02: The ticket costs 500$.
Sam: 13:50:31: And the flight departs at 8 am"""

import re
from itertools import groupby

out = []
for v, g in groupby(chat_segment.splitlines(), lambda k: re.findall(r'^\w+:\s', k)):
    if not v:
        continue
    out.append(v[0] + ' '.join(re.findall(r'^\w+:\s[\d:]+:\s*(.*)', val)[0] for val in g))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=120)
```

Prints:

```
['Visitor: I want to book a ticket from Thailand to Hawai On 18th this month',
 'Sam: Hi Which class would you like the ticket in?',
 'Visitor: Business',
 'Sam: Give me a minute to check availability',
 'Visitor: ok',
 'Sam: Only one ticket available on 18th in business class. The ticket costs 500$. And the flight departs at 8 am']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Andrej Kesely, I was raking my brains since yesterday for this solution. Thank you again.